# can we use google nearby api without internet or wifi routers

Tags: android

I'm trying to use google nearby api but from the documents that i have read it seems that to use google nearby api requires wifi router or internet connection So if there is anybody who have some idea about this situation i am here waiting.

Comment: without internet connection how you get data from google api..

Comment: big no.. not possible..

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

I did not want to add anything here other than the word "NO". But, SO did not allow me.

Comment: So what is the use of using Bluetooth and sound for connection I don't get it .it means if I developed an app it must have internet connection even though it only want to use Bluetooth ?

Comment: can you please elaborate on, what you meant by "Bluetooth and sound"?

Comment: i mean how do i connect if my device is with out internet connection and still i turned  Bluetooth on  will i still identify the devices around me

Answer (score 0):

Good news, since the last update on June 2017, with the API v11, you have offline support, you don't even need Internet permission to use Google Nearby.

> **Offline support**. Nearby Connections now works fully offline, no network connectivity required. Devices no longer need to be connected to the same multicast-enabled wifi network to discover or connect to each other. [Google Nearby Documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/v11-update)

Comment: can you share any post or blog link with working code because i am not able to achieve offline support and google message sample code was last updated 2years back https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages

Comment: Hello, it is the **Connections API** that works offline and not the Messages API.
Here is a link you can try : [Connections API sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/connections/rockpaperscissors)